# Beginner : How to Colorize depending on displacement height?

Tags: modeling, materials, displacement

I am starting to experiment with blender nodes and displacement, my goal was to create a texture where the high displaced areas are white and the low displaced areas are black.

I generated a Musgrave texture and used the output as both surface and displacement, however, some top areas appears black and some lower areas appears white, what am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that it's that you're using different normals for displacement as for the Musgrave texture.  Run the output of the Texture Coordinates Object to the displacement input.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly why your nodes don't work but there are a few issues. Unfortunately, Blender's documentation is very vague sometimes.

First, it seems that the *Object Coordinates* are not the right choice for the *Musgrave Texture*. The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html) doesn't tell what this is exactly. But it's better to use the *Generated* ouput here.

Second, the *Height* of the *[Musgrave Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/render/shader_nodes/textures/musgrave.html)* ranges from `-1` to `1` and **not** from `0` to `1`. Because you set the *Midlevel* of the *Displacement* to `0.5` everything is a bit off as a result.

Don't worry, I also wasn't aware of this and the documentation is here very vague again:

> Musgrave - Height
>
> Texture value.

Ah yes, now it's clear! ;-)

Ok, the range is then revealed in the example below in the documentation and it shows how to map it properly into the range of 0 to 1 with a *Map Range* node.

Knowing this, we now can fix the material:

[image: screenshot of the nodes]